# Find expression in python

Tags: python, regex

String example: 'file_name.c: 120' or 'file_name.m: 312'
Target: find exactly '.c:' or '.m:' using regular expression.

Since it's confusing issue, I would to get a good tutorial for regular expression if someone knows.

Ron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
string = 'file_name.c: 120'
find = re.findall("(\.[cm])*", string)
find = filter(None, find)
print find
```

I prefer using findall as I am guessing you may be looking for more than one example.

Answer (score 1):

There's an introduction to regular expressions (in Python) here: http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html#regex-howto

```
import re
pat = re.compile(r'\.[cm]:')
print pat.search('file_name.c: 120').group(0)
print pat.search('file_name.m: 312').group(0)
```